# Finitely generated modules in short exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ be a short exact sequence of $R$-modules where $R$ is a ring.

1. Show that if $B$ is finitely generated, then $A$ and $C$ don't have to be finitely generated.
2. If $R$ is a PID and $B$ is finitely generated, then are $A$ and $C$ finitely generated?

I know that if $A$ and $C$ are finitely generated, then $B$ is also finitely generated. It would be nice if this statement would be and iff statement but it isn't, but I suppose that it is true if $R$ is a PID. For the first question I thought of finding a counter example, but I can't come up with one. And for the second question I can't even see why it would be true by just knowing that is a PID (it might not be true though).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $B$ is finitely generated, then so is $C$: given any finite set $X$ of generators of $X$, and any element $c\in C$, there exists $b\in B$ that maps to $c$, and expressing $b$ in terms of $X$ gives you way to express $c$ in terms of the images of the elements of $X$. What 1 is really saying is that it is possible for $B$ to be finitely generated without **both** $A$ and $C$ being finitely generated. A counterexample will have $A$ not be finitely generated.

Comment: For the second part, look up the proof that a subgroup of a finitely generated abelian group is finitely generated; the same argument works over any PID.

Comment: As a further hint, the question of whether $A$ must be finitely generated will be closely related to the question of whether $R$ is a Noetherian ring.

Answer (score 1):

You can take $R$ to be a non-Noetherian ring, for example $\mathbb{R}[X_1,X_2,\dots]$. Then $R$ is obviously a finitely generated module over $R$, but $I=\langle X_1, X_2,\dots\rangle$ is not a finitely generated module over $R$. You get the following exact sequence $0\to I\to R\to R/I\to 0$, with $R$ finitely generated over $R$ but $I$ isn't. Note that as noted in the comments, $R/I$ would necessarily be finitely generated over $R$.

Remark: Every non-Noetherian ring would do, as a ring is Noetherian iff every submodule of finitely generated module is finitely generated. This gives you that in the case of $2$, $A$ and $C$ must be finitely generated, as $A$ can be considered as a submodule of the finitely generated module $B$, and since being PID implies being Noetherian.